# Facebook login along with standard login confusion

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I currently have a website with standard email+password mysql login and I have implemented Facebook Login.

I would like to keep both living together, however I have a little bit of confusion about how I should do it correctly.

In the standard implementation I check if user and pwd are correct then I log the user.

In Facebook login JS after I log the user I have id and email, how can I link it to the existing standard account safely?
After the JS login I could send an ajax request to mysql (a php script) and see if the email+id couple exists, but this way anyone knowing the email and the id of the fb account could do it through a post request and it wouldn't be safe.

What would be the right way to do it?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Send only the access token to the server, and then use it to make an API request to get user id and email from there.

Comment: What do you mean more precisely? After the login function I can get the token but how do it link it to the existing profile?

Comment: You fetch the FB email via API - and then you go check in your database, if you find a user account with that email.

Comment: (Be aware though, that you will not _get_ an email address for every user from Facebook - for example if they signed up using their mobile, they might not even have an email on file with Facebook.)

Comment: Ok, but I am actually using FB.api('/me', {fields: 'first_name, last_name, email'} to fetch the email and I do not add any token, however it does still work, am I doing it wrong? The user is logged in.

Comment: `FB.api` is _client-side_ code, that's from the JS SDK - and that handles adding the token to the API calls for you.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I won't need the token, right? At this point what should I store on the DB to check if the user is correct?

Comment: You do need to the token, to request user id and email in a _safe_ way - on the server side. Using `FB.api` doesn't win you anything, because that is client-side, and any data it gives you, you would still have to send to the server first (so the user could intercept/manipulate it.)

Comment: Doesn't FB provide only the JS SDK for client-side calls?

Comment: For use of their API on the frontend, that is the main thing they provide, yes. But really anything capable of making HTTP requests can make API calls.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So how can I make a call to /me, with the access token? I mean what the url would be?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview